# how to change the order of columns in a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

How to change the position of the columns in a matrix, in the manner of the last column in M, sea the first in G, the second column in M, sea the penultimate in G and so on

for example

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    5    9   13
[2,]    2    6   10   14
[3,]    3    7   11   15
[4,]    4    8   12   16
```

and I want

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    13    9    5   1
[2,]    14    10   6   2
[3,]    15    11   7   3
[4,]    16    12   8   4
```

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest way would be -

```
mat[, ncol(mat):1]

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   13    9    5    1
[2,]   14   10    6    2
[3,]   15   11    7    3
[4,]   16   12    8    4
```

Comment: I'm very thick this morning;-) cleanest option! no need for `apply`. +1

Comment: You certainly are! ;-) Happens to everyone though so not a big deal.